YOLO8 на Raspberry PI4
Сейчас пытался запустить YOLOv8 на Raspberry Pi4. На нем стоит собственная OS на основе Debian и Python 3.11. Пример взял с сайта https://docs.ultralytics.com/guides/raspberry-pi/
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip -y
pip install -U pip
pip install ultralytics[export]
sudo reboot

сам скрипт:
from ultralytics import YOLO
# Load a YOLOv8n PyTorch model
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
# Export the model to NCNN format
model.export(format="ncnn")  # creates 'yolov8n_ncnn_model'
# Load the exported NCNN model
ncnn_model = YOLO("yolov8n_ncnn_model")
# Run inference
results = ncnn_model("https://ultralytics.com/images/bus.jpg")

При импорте YOLO выдает illegal instruction.
Мое сильное подозрение, что эта версия Питона не совместима с библиотекой torch.
Пока поставил Python 3.9 - работает. Но это слишком криво.
Может кто расскажет, как сделать, если установили нормально YOLO с Python 3.11?

пожалуйста, добавьте чуть больше деталей, например, точную ошибку, которую вы получаете (если возможно), и конкретные шаги, которые вы уже предприняли. Это поможет тем, кто может ответить, быстрее понять вашу ситуацию и предложить более точное решение.
